# Using mdf or sdf for saving in database file

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

I have a simple question. I am writing a program in c# where I can draw shapes in a canvas.

However, I want to save the values of those shapes in a local database file which I can then use on whatever computer I'm trying to use this program without having to install something else (database wise etc.).

So my question now is if I should use a `.sdf` (SQL Server CE) or `.mdf` (SQL Server) file for this purpose. And is there a big difference using them with c# code?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Since `.mdf` is a **SQL Server** file, this will **always** require some database installation - either on that PC, or somewhere in the network. Only SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition - `.sdf` file) can be totally *embedded* into your application and deployed as a handful of DLL's alongside your application. Too bad it's being deprecated by Microsoft in favor of SQL Server *Express* (`.mdf`  files, installation required)

Comment: Ok so mdf is not an option then. However, can I still use and edit .sdf files somehow? Or is this totally out of the question now?

Comment: No, you can still use the software - it's viable, it works - just don't expect any future development and new features with it. If it's all you need - go for it!

Comment: Yes its all i need. But how do I use, create or edit a sdf file in visual studio 2013 now? There no option to do so.

Comment: There's a great free tool called [SQL Server CE Toolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) which you can install into Visual Studio or run separately. It allows you to do all you need to do with SQL Server CE database files (`.sdf`)

Comment: Well thank you very much then.